# Where to download list of all US OTC stocks

Tags: market-data, ticker-mapping

Where can I download a complete list of US OTC stocks? https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=symboldirdefs only has lists of exchange-listed stocks, not OTC stocks. There is FINRA's OTC [Symbol Directory](https://otce.finra.org/otce/symbol-directory) and OTC Markets' [Company Directory](https://www.otcmarkets.com/corporate-services/company-directory), but these lists are not available for download.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when FINRA shut down OTC BB in Nov 2021, the symbol list that was previously produced daily on ftp.otcbb.com was also discontinued.

OTC Markets offer a daily security master file:
https://www.otcmarkets.com/market-data/reference-and-pricing-data/security-data
for a fee.

An alternative is to use a data vendor that has complete currently-listed OTC coverage.

Also note that there are typically hundreds of corporate actions per month relating to OTC securities, particularly symbol changes, which must be tracked to maintain a consistent database.  This is a significant task.

Full disclosure: Norgate Data provides OTC data, and I am a co-owner of Norgate Data.